# How create dynamic form with angular and Mat-select option

Tags: angular

I have an Angular app, and I'm trying to make a dynamic form with Mat-select for the type, and I want to add or remove a field depending on the chosen type.

i so want on this field show if type is null or O.

In future  i want more controle on input.

And is ngif not going to generate an error for me because it does not exist.

```html
 <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
        
        <div *ngIf="typeB" class="form-group">
            <mat-label>Type B</mat-label>
            <mat-select id="typeb">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let type of typeB" [value]="type.value">
                {{type.viewValue}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </div>
        
<div *ngIf="f['typeb'] == null || f['typeb'].value == 'O'" class="form-group">
            <label for="idStr">identifiant</label>
            <input
                formControlName="idStr"
                id="idStr"
                type="text"
                class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
...
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-create',
  templateUrl: './create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create.component.scss']
})
export class CreateComponent implements OnInit {

  form!: FormGroup;
  typeB = [
    { value: 'A', viewValue: 'APP'},
    { value: 'O', viewValue: 'ORG' },
    { value: 'P', viewValue: 'PER' },
  ];

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) { }

  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      typeb: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
      idStr: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      ...
    });
      },
      error: (e) => {
        alert(e.status + " - " + e.error.message);
      }
    });
  }

  get f() {
    return this.form.controls;
  }
```

with this code the field is always invisible

If add console.log on function f , I see in the console it's typeb it's always null

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but `typeB` is not declared.

So the select is not showing.

Comment: typeB exists sorry I made a typo and `f['typeB']` or `f['typeb']` same result

Answer (score 0):

Try tro change that `*ngIf="f['typeb'] == null || f['typeb'].value == 'O'"` by

```
*ngIf="f['typeb'].value == null || f['typeb'].value == 'O'"
```

Comment: if i add value ,it's always show

Answer (score 0):

I sorry i'm forgot formControlName